# Shutdown Block Reason API for WPF is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, shutdown

I have application, which should block Windows shutdown in particular situations (or at least notify user, that he should not shutdown PC yet). I'm using Shutdown Blocking Reason API mentioned [here](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/25/Windows-Vista-_2D00_-ShutdownBlockReasonCreate-in-C_2300_.aspx) (and in some other places).

The thing is, that when I'm using this for Winforms, it works well, as long as I'm using it from Form directly

```
ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(this.Handle, text));
```

Once I've migrated to WPF, I've changed it to next way

```
ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle, text));
```

It is called from `MainWindow.xaml.cs`.
The problem is, that it does nothing. No exception is thrown, but it does nothing on Windows shutdown.
So, is it incompatible with WPF, or something else?

Answer (score 3):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to know for sure what the problem in your case is. I do know of at least two possible reasons this wouldn't work:

1. The `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()` method is called too soon. I have found that if you attempt to use `WindowInteropHelper` in the `Window` class's constructor, using the HWND retrieved that way to call `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()`, the block reason isn't created. However, if you delay initialization to the `Loaded` event for the `Window` object, it works.
2. You are not also responding to the `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` message. In WPF, the easiest way to accomplish this is to add a handler to the `SystemEvents.SessionEnding` event.
3. You are allowing the window to close. Naturally, if the window doesn't remain, it's no longer around to report a reason to block shutting down.

Here is a complete code example that, on my machine, works fine. That is, if you attempt to shutdown the computer, the program will show up in the list of active programs that are blocking shutdown, and the given block reason text is displayed under the program name:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestSO33876255BlockShutdown.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

  <StackPanel>
    <CheckBox Content="Allow window to close" IsChecked="{Binding AllowClose}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**C#:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public bool AllowClose { get; set; }

    private WindowInteropHelper _helper;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += (sender, e) =>
        {
            _helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
            _helper.EnsureHandle();

            SystemEvents.SessionEnding += (s1, e1) =>
            {
                if (e1.Reason == SessionEndReasons.SystemShutdown)
                {
                    Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => MessageBox.Show("attempting to block shutdown"));
                    e1.Cancel = true;
                }
            };

            if (!ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(_helper.Handle, "Testing Stack Overflow Block Reason"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to create shutdown-block reason. Error: "
                    + Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message);
            }
        };
    }

    protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!AllowClose)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy(_helper.Handle);
        }
        base.OnClosing(e);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public extern static bool ShutdownBlockReasonCreate([In]IntPtr hWnd, [In] string pwszReason);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public extern static bool ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy([In]IntPtr hWnd);
}
```